# Counterweight requirement and platform design for motorised speaker stand stability

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, structures

I recently bought my dream speakers (Dutch & Dutch 8c), but at the cost of having to preserve a minimalist interior for the sake of household peace. To that effect, I plan to construct motorised speaker stands that will allow me to hide the speakers inside 2 stools (illustration attached).
[image]
2 main questions please:

A. In the following configuration **what weight will I require at the base in order to maintain stability:**

Individual speaker weight: 24kg (+ whatever the mount it's attached to will weigh - see question 2).

Speaker dimensions: 48.5h x 27w x 38 d

Lift column width: 6cm, assume gap between lift column and speaker may be around 2cm or less

Column min height = 52cm, stroke = 66cm so base of speaker may lift up to 66cm from the ground (though likely only needs to be 49cm).

The weighted base will sit underneath the speaker and not to the other side of the motorised lift column (due to space constraints in this plan I can't have the counterweight on the other side of the column)

Lift column I'll likely use:

https://cdn.linak.com/-/media/files/data-sheet-source/en/lifting-column-dl12-data-sheet-eng.pdf

no weight listed unfortunately

B. I need to create a bracket that connects to the top of the column, and the bottom of the speaker.
[image]

**What thickness steel or other material would I need to use to stably support the speaker weight of 24kg without any deformation**, and ideally minimising vibration/ resonance.

How will the weight affect the calculation above?

Is single sided support sufficient with a sturdy support?

Design constraints:
[image]

- Height to bottom of table 73cm - There is a table that is both lower than the required height of the speaker when extended, and limits the max height of the column if the column is to be placed beneath the table and not on the other side of the speaker.
- The stool height should be kept as low as possible - a lift column with retracted height of 518mm is the best I could find.
- The stool should jot out as little as possible from the table perimeter - this is of course constrained by the speaker width, but also by the column and any necessary gap. I've accounted for 8-12cm in addition to speaker width covering a 2-4cm gap + column width of 6cm + thickness of stool, ideally I'd get this lower.

Alternatives:

1. Find track linear actuators that can: a. support the speaker weight, b. add minimal height between the track and base (so they don't add height to the stool) - here I've seen actuators that have the motor parallel to the rail, but their lift capacities or sizes are not suitable.

In this scenario I could attach 1 actuator on each side of the stool, if I can coordinate their action.

Overall this could be the most elegant solution, but may be beyond my capabilities to implement if there isn't a relatively put together solution

2. Use a tatami electric lifting column and fit it so it rises beneath the table, rather than on the outer side of the speaker.

I could get away with a stroke height of 43cm (minimum height required for the speaker driver to clear the stool), but not sure it's ideal without full speaker clearance of the stool.

https://www.progressiveautomations.com/products/flt-11

Thank you!!

Comment: Why not use a big threaded rod? There is a square thread that should work, see https://www.rolledthreads.com/acme-threads

Comment: Thanks. So your suggestion is to build my own external linear actuator essentially? With a threaded rod attached to a motor shaft, and a threaded screw secured against a guide?